# Is "array[n] != '\0'" better than "n < strlen(array)"?

Tags: c++

For a

```
char array [10];
cin.getline(array, 10);
```

which of these is the best option?

```
for(int n = 0; array[n] != '\0'; n++) {...}
```

or

```
for(int n = 0; n < strlen(array); n++) {...}
```

Comment: Why not just use std::string?

Comment: @Nir Friedman It's just a generic question about arrays, instead it could be an int array.

Comment: People don't null terminate int arrays, so I don't see how this is reasonably applicable to int arrays.

Comment: And assuming that you want to do something with `array[n]` inside the loop, this may actually be one of those rare cases where I would go hardcore and do something like `for(char* c = &a; *a != '\0'; ++a ) { /* use *a to get the current character */ }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second method is very poor, because `strlen()` has to scan the entire array every time you call it, to search for the `0` byte.

You can improve it a bit by calling `strlen` once before the loop:

```
size_t len = strlen(array);
for (int n = 0; n < len; n++) { ... }
```

That requires scanning the array once, in addition to the scan done by the `for` loop.

Some compilers may be able to detect that the array doesn't change during the loop, so they can optimize your `strlen()` version into this second one. But I don't think it's a great idea to depend on it.

But just checking the element directly avoids any extra scans, so it's most efficient. It's not likely that any other approach could be optimized better than this.

Comment: Modern compilers perform this optimization (old ones probably do too)

Answer (score 0):

It’s generally more efficient to scan an array once rather than twice, so you should use the first approach almost all the time.  In most real-world situations, you should also be checking for buffer overruns, so you would write something like either:

```
// This only works for arrays, not pointers!  With pointers, buffer size is a parameter.
constexpr size_t buf_size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < buf_size && array[i]; ++i )
  do_stuff_with(array[i]);
```

Or:

```
// This only works for arrays, not pointers!
constexpr size_t buf_size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
const size_t m = strnlen_s( array, buf_size );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i )
  do_stuff_with(array[i]);
```

The main reason you might want to use the second approach is that you will need to look up the length of the string soon anyway, for example to allocate memory for a deep copy or to do a substring match within the loop.  In that case, finding the length just once is more efficient and you might as well use it in your loop condition, too.

## Addendum

Several comments suggested using STL data structures.  This is good advice.  To use a `std::array` or `std::vector` named `a`, replace the first two lines of the first example with `const size_t buf_size = a.size();`.  To use a `std::string` named `s`, replace the first three lines of the second example with `const size_t m = s.size();`.

Comment: If you are using C++11 you may as well use `std::array` which knows its size.

Comment: and in any C++ version there is `std::string` that knows its size too, and you don't need to scan the string multiple times

Comment: Why is there an '&& array[i]' in the first for?

Comment: @EmmanuelMess It's testing two conditions: you're within the size of the array, and the element of the array is not zero.

Comment: The first example should work with a `std::array`, and the second  on a `std::string`, with minor modification.  Change the expression to calculate length according to the data type you use.